# Access dynamic object property in Typo3 Fluid template

Tags: typo3, fluid

I have an object in a Typo3 Fluid template and want to access a property on it, but the name of the property is in a variable `someProperty`:

```
<f:if condition="searchObject.{someProperty}">
        Found!
</f:if>
```

Because this does not work: Is there a built in way to access a property by variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can give a chance to [fedex Fluid viewhelper collection](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Variable/GetViewHelper.html) and its  `v:var.get` viewhelper.

Or check the other viewhelpers in here. If you do not find a suitable one, you can write your own for this functionality based on some example here.

**UPDATE:**

Since this is an old question to TYPO3 6.2 it is the time to update it to the current standards. (See also the answer of Claus Due:

For the current LTS: TYPO3 9.5, you can use simple:

```
{searchObject.{someProperty}}
```

Comment: So there is nothing built in for this?

Comment: I don't think, that there is anything. Fluid has a basic working in its core, but there are many extension to it. Like the one above.

Comment: I read somewhere that nested variable access is a feature in TYPO3 v9. It shouldn't  be possible with Fluid below v9 or at least only lowlevel support. You'll have to use `EXT:vhs'.

Answer (score 2):

In Fluid standalone and TYPO3v8 and upward:

`{array.{variableContainingKey}}`.

Answer (score 0):

The point notation actually is the correct way to access a property. What do you mean by dynamic? Can be null? Have you tried the following?

```
<f:if condition="<f:count>{searchObject.someProperty}</f:count>">
    Found!
</f:if>
```

Or maybe just:

```
<f:if condition="{searchObject.someProperty}">
    Found!
</f:if>
```

Comment: I think the question is about dynamical property reading. So let say, the code needs to checck, has the object an XYZ property or not. So the {someProperty} in this case is a variable and could have different values: XYZ, ZYX, YYY, and so on. It is not so simple.

Comment: Oh okay, got it! Can't you resolve the variable with the propertyname in the controller?